# Link in email triggered by antimalware / antispam software

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

We have an in house web application and recently we've added the ability for users to approve/reject requests from within their email, no need to access our system or login

Essentially this is done by generating a special token for each request and adding a link to the generated email that points to a webhook.

The issue we have is some of our clients antispam / antimalware software is "checking" these links by essentially opening them and checking the link is safe.

The issue is because these checks are opening the links its triggering the approve/reject events. I'm wondering if there is a way we can detect if the link is opened by a user or somehow obfuscate the link.

I've been playing around with the header information when the link is triggered but I can't seem to find a reliable way to tell the difference between a user and software

Comment: Hi brendonrother welcome to StackOverflow. This is indeed a pretty annoying behavior. You could read the `user-agent` but if I were building an anti-malware software I would have thought of that and fake my `user-agent`. I think the best useability option for your scenario, is to add a button on that page to confirm the action taken.

Comment: @zzarbi yes that's what I'm leaning towards, was just trying to see if there was more user friendly method, and yes the anti-malware is sending user-agent